# Spring boot (JPA Test) : Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration when doing a JpaTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to run a simple Junit test to see if my JpaRepository are indeed working.

The error I keep getting is:

```
Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test java.lang.IllegalStateException doesn't spring boot configure itself?
```

My Test Class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class LogConnectionTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private LogConnectionDao logConnectionDao;

    @Test
    public void ajouterTest() throws Exception{
        this.entityManager.persist(new LogConnection("Test",4));
        LogConnection logConnection = this.logConnectionDao.findOne((long)1);
        assertThat(logConnection.getClasseName().equals("Test"));
        assertThat(logConnection.getOriginalId() != 5);
    }
}
```

My Spring boot application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UpsysmarocLibraryLogApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UpsysmarocLibraryLogApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Repository :

```
public interface LogConnectionDao extends JpaRepository<LogConnection,Long> {

}
```

Comment: you need to use the `SpringBootTest` annotation on your `LogConnectionTest` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get it. Follow below convention

1> Assume your main spring application is as below

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {...}
```

2> Now create a abstract class which you can extend in all test classes. If you dont need this, then just take these config annotations and directly put in your test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebAppConfiguration
/**
 * If you have any property file to load to test uncomment below line) 
   @TestPropertySource({
   "classpath:/properties/dbConfig-test.properties",
   "classpath:/properties/unittest.properties"
   })
*/
public abstract class AbstractSpringTest{}
```

Then you can have your test class

```
public class LogConnectionTest extends AbstractSpringTest {

/** Instance to unit test. */
@Autowired
private LogConnectionDao logConnectionDao;

@Test
public void ajouterTest() {
    final LogConnection logConnection = logConnectionDao.saveAndFlush(new LogConnection("Test",4));
    Assert.assertNotNull(logConnection);
    Assert.assertEquals("Test", logConnection.getClasseName());
    Assert.assertNotEquals(5, logConnection.getOriginalId());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use below class level annotation on your test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JPAConfig.class})
```

or

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JPAConfig.class})
```

or

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value={"myJPAConfig.xml"})
```

or

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value={"myJPAConfig.xml"})
```

Comment: what is JPAConfig ?

Comment: There must be any configuration file, either any java class (Annotation based configuration) or xml file, where you have provided JPA configuration. You need to mention it as argument to ContextConfiguration annotation. I have updated my answer

Comment: Can you please provide the example of JPAConfig class?